# how do i pass form data from one jsp page to another?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

i need to transfer data from 1.jsp to 2.jsp

there will be checkboxes and radio buttons and drop downs which i need to pass from 1.jsp to 2.jsp, then ill use that data in 2.jsp to generate the proper page

is there a way of doing so without passing that info through the url?

heres my fiddle for the form: http://jsfiddle.net/S2SxN/10/

so if i have a form with a radio button id="extra" i can get the value of it when i submit it in 1.jsp to 2.jsp right?!?

1.jsp:

```
<form name="form1" id="form" action="/2.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>I am interested in:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="consume" id="con"/> Cosuming and/or distributing OTC Markets data
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="extranet" id="extra"/> Providing connectivity to OTC Markets(Extranet)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" id="re">
                <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

2.jsp:

```
<% if(request.getParameter("extra") != null) { %>
    <h2>you selected <%= request.getParameter("extra") %></h2>
<% } else { %>
    <h2>you selected <%= request.getParameter("con") %></h2>
<% } %>
```

some reason im getting the "con" result and not the "extra", when i do get the "con" result is it null...
what am i doing wrong???

Comment: submit the form to 2.jsp and make Request.getParameter("") your friend.

Comment: This may be heavier than you need, but you can certainly store it in a database.

Comment: i think @JHolyhead  is right. Is not just use HTML ways to send it as `POST` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the form to 2.jsp as a post and get the values back out of the post data. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Sorry then, I've already got a vote down because an answer like yours. Nevermind...

Comment: so i should set the action of 1.jsp to 2.jsp...

as in <form action="2.jsp"> then use jquery or js to pass the data over??

Comment: set action to 2.jsp and method to post. Then you can retrieve all of the form values with Request.getParameter("formElementName"). There's an example at http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/UsingPostMethod.shtml

Comment: doesnt seem to be working for me =/ i set action to 2.jsp and in 2.jsp i do request.getParameter("extra") to check if it is null, which it is
just added some code, can u check if im doing it correctly?

Comment: add method="post" in the form tag